# Image Segmentation - Segmented Overlay Perspective

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, image-segmentation, onnx

i have a function that return this image:

[image: Segmented result with image overlay]

But this result not same like i want.
i want to make the image overlay (MY LOGO) to same perspective like the segmented part (the white background)
this is my function to achieve this result:

def draw_masks(image, boxes, class_ids, mask_alpha=1.0, mask_maps=None):
mask_img = image.copy()

```
# Draw bounding boxes and labels of detections
for i, (box, class_id) in enumerate(zip(boxes, class_ids)):
    overlay_image_path = 'mylogo.png'
    overlay_image = cv2.imread(overlay_image_path)

    x1, y1, x2, y2 = box.astype(int)
    width = x2 - x1
    height = y2 - y1

    # Resize the overlay image to match the size of the crop_mask_img
    overlay_image = cv2.resize(overlay_image, (width, height))

    # Get the segmentation mask
    if mask_maps is None:
        cv2.rectangle(mask_img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 0, 255), -1)
    else:
        crop_mask = mask_maps[i][y1:y2, x1:x2, np.newaxis]
        crop_mask_img = mask_img[y1:y2, x1:x2]                          
    
        # Find outermost contour of the segmentation mask
        contours, _ = cv2.findContours(crop_mask.astype(np.uint8), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        if len(contours) > 0:
            contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
            hull = cv2.convexHull(contour)

            # Draw lines connecting the four outermost points
            drawcountour = cv2.drawContours(crop_mask_img, [hull], -1, (255, 255, 255), thickness=cv2.FILLED)
                          
        crop_mask_img = crop_mask_img * (1 - crop_mask) + crop_mask * overlay_image
        mask_img[y1:y2, x1:x2] = crop_mask_img
        
solid_overlay = cv2.addWeighted(mask_img, mask_alpha, image, 1 - mask_alpha, 0)
return solid_overlay
```

Result that i want :

- The logo is same as the perspective of segmented part
- The segmented part is smooth (white part)(have a straight line on point to point (top left, top right, bottom left and bottom right)
  [image]

Input image:

[image: Input Image]

Logo image:

[image: Logo image]

Segmented Image:
[image: Segmented Image]

Comment: Provide your input image and logo image so others can properly test and fix your code

Comment: How did you segment the license plate? It is nearly the same color as the car. Do you have a segmented image showing the license region apart from the rest of the image?

Comment: I segment the license plate using onnx model with yolo

Comment: Provide the segmented image or the corners of the license so that I can work with either.

Comment: I already update the segmented image

Comment: The segmented image is of no use unless you know where its top left corner comes from in the original image. Do you have that coordinate?